# clojure - why does this code transpose a nested structure

Tags: clojure

Say I have a nested structure like this:

```
(def board [[:x :e :e]
[:o :x :e]
[:o :e :x]])
```

Why does this code transpose it 90%

```
(apply map vector board)
```

Comment: If you want 100% transposition, use `mapv` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` makes the code equivalent to this:

```
(map vector [:x :e :e] [:o :x :e] [:o :e :x])
```

`map` will then execute, in sequence:

```
(vector :x :o :o) ;; the first elements in the sequences
(vector :e :x :e) ;; the second elements in the sequences
(vector :e :e :x) ;; the third elements in the sequences
```

And collect them in a sequence to return.  This has the effect of making the "columns" in your original sequence the new rows, and the "rows" in your original sequence the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

[Apply](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/apply) "`(apply f x args)` Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening arguments to args"

What's happening is that `vector` is prepended to `board`, making the expression `(apply map (cons vector board))`, when the list `(cons vector board)` is spliced out into `map` by `apply` it becomes the expression given in YosemiteMark's answer.